# JavaScript IP regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, ip, netmask

I need a JavaScript code that changes the IP address into rexexp,
 i.e: `123.123.123.123` to `^123\.123\.123\.123$` and the same operation for netmask. 
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I think you need to explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would you want a regular expression like that? A string comparison would be much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Look like you could write something like `ip = '^' + ip + '$'`. But then what?

Comment: It is as easy as `str.replace(/\./g, "\\.")`

Answer (score 2):

Well, just a shot into the dark:

```
var ipaddr = '123.123.123.123',
    myRegEx = new RegExp('^' + ipaddr + '$');
```

That will generate a `RegExp object` with the string `'^123.123.123.123$'` and could get used like

```
myRegEx.exec( someStringVariable ); // returns an array of matches
```

This can be very useful when you need to build a regular expression "in-code" with variables. If you just want to have a string compare, you should go for the equivalance operator `==` or `===` or use the `.indexOf()` method.

Ref.: [RegExp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp)

---

**Update**

To replace the periods within a string, simply use the `.replace()` method.

```
var ipaddr = '123.123.123.123';

ipaddr = '^' + ipaddr.replace( /\./g, '\\.' ) + '$';
```

Comment: In theory periods should be escaped, but yeah, according to the question's condition it's ok :)

Comment: @Karolis: good point, totally overseen it. Of course the periods need to get escaped in a realworld scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Quentin. Use indexOf instead:

```
if (searchString.indexOf("123.123.123.123", 0) != -1) {
    alert("Yo");
}
```

Perhaps you need to explain the problem better.

Comment: well, the point is when I enter some IP address I want the script to change it to regular expression